# How to determine which cell from datagrid is edited in BeginningEdit event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an event on my datagrid `BeginningEdit` and I want to determine which cell fired the event. Sender is always the DataGrid, not the cell itself. I need to do this in `BeginningEdit` because I have an if statement there that cancels event under specific condition. If specific cell fired the event I want that cell to skip the if statement.

```
private void XpcbDataGrid_OnBeginningEdit(object? sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GlobalStructures.StructureTable st in GlobalStructures.Parts.Where(st =>
                     st.Quantity == (XpcbDataGrid.SelectedItem as GlobalPcbData.Costs)?.Ilosc))
    {
        foreach (GlobalStructures.Type type in st.Structures.Where(type => type.Grupa == Group))
        {
            if (type.Typ == "PCB")
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the info in e.Column & e.Row

Comment: Hey, everyone working in this have lot of 'How I didn't see this by myself before' moments, so no apologies ;)